# SQL- Creating a Date and time count for an event

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am newer to SQL

My dataset is:

```
ID   Date  Group  Event1   Event2   
1   4-1-12   1      0         0
1   4-2-12   1      0         0
1   4-16-12  2      1         0
1   4-16-12  2      1         1
```

I need to create a variable called Marker that counts as 1 if Event 1 occurred first and then event2 occurred within 1 day of event 1. So the only line where Marker should equal 1 is the fourth line. The rest should all be 0.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Read carefully the http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the logic correctly, you can do this with window functions:

```
select id, date, group, event1, event2,
       (case when FirstEvent1Date < FirstEvent2Date and
                  FirstEvent2Date <= dateadd(day, 1, FirstEvent1Date)
             then 1 else 0
        end) as Marker
from (select ds.*,
             min(case when event1 = 1 then date end) over (partition by group) as FirstEvent1Date,
             min(case when event2 = 1 then date end) over (partition by group) as FirstEvent2Date,
      from dataset ds
     ) ds;
```

Note that your question has column names such as `group` that are reserved words.  I have used these without escaping them.  Using reserved words for column names is a bad idea; it makes code harder to write and read.

Comment: Thanks. I actually didn't name it group :), just put that there to get the very basic version. But it is working so far. I just had to put the very very basic version.